# Troubleshooting Win2003 DNS issues

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain-name-system

I have a strange issue:

We have two DNS servers, both are Windows 2003 SP2.  The only difference between the two is they have seperate gateways to the internet.  One goes out through a cable modem, the other goes out through a 10MB metro-ethernet service.

Both servers appear to work fine, having no issues, all clients are able to resolve internal and external DNS querries, with one exception.  When doing an nslookup on the first server, I receive a timeout messgae for one and only one particular domain.  The other server doesn't not receive a timeout for that same domain, it works fine.

When looking at the domain in question, I see no issues, I'm able to ping it from other computers outside my network, etc.  How can I troubleshoot the reason for this particular domain lookup failing on only this DNS server?

Things I've done so far:
1. Reset the cache on both server.
2. Restart both servers
3. Turn debugging on, but nothing is showing up in the logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I would do: install a packet capture program on the DNS server in question (Microsoft Network Monitor works well), start a capture using a filter for DNS traffic, run nslookup for the domain in question, wait until nslookup times out, stop the capture and analyze the DNs traffic to see where the issue is occurring.

Comment: Good idea.  I was hoping there was a debug/error log I could turn on more easily and get some info, but if there isn't then I might go this route.